# How to find out the distance from the bottom safe area edge to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, safearealayoutguide

I need to calculate the distance between the bottom anchor of the safe area and the bottom of the screen. Is there a way to do that in code given a view?

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why you would want that distance ? This value may change based on orientation. Why don't you use `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide`   and layout anchors to do this for you ?

Comment: @user1046037 perhaps for animating something off the screen bottom then back up again

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this one

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
}
```

Comment: You can also get this property from the current view controllers `view` property `self.view.safeAreaInsets`

Answer (score 1):

You could try pinning a subview (clear , hidden or whatever) to the bottom of the safeAreaLayoutGuide and calculate the difference between the bottom of this view and your view controller's view in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let measuringView = UIView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        measuringView.backgroundColor = .magenta
        measuringView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(measuringView)
        let vConstraint = measuringView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        let heightConstraint = measuringView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34)
        var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|[measuring]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["measuring": measuringView])
        constraints.append(vConstraint)
        constraints.append(heightConstraint)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let measuringBottom = measuringView.frame.origin.y + measuringView.frame.height
        let viewBottom = view.bounds.height
        let distance = abs(measuringBottom - viewBottom)
        print("distance is \(distance) points")
    }
}
```

[image: measuring distance]

Answer (score 1):

To re-iterate previous answers. Pin a subview to the bottom of the view of a `UIViewController`. Then pin a second one to the `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor` anchor of the view. With both subviews pinning the `top`, `leading` and `trailing` anchors of the parent view. Then, I would assume in `viewDidAppear`, you could print out the difference between the two subview's `frame.maxY` values. This should give you the difference.

```
let viewA = UIView()

let viewB = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    view.addSubview(viewA)
    view.addSubview(viewB)
    viewA.translateAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints = false
    viewB.translateAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints = false


        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([viewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
                                         viewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
                                         viewA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
                                         viewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
                                         viewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
                                         viewB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
                                         viewB.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
                                         viewB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)])
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

}

override func viewDidAppear() {

    super.viewDidAppear()
    print("Safe Distance Value is:\(viewA.frame.maxY - viewB.frame.maxY)")

}
```

As a reference for others, the value appears to be `34` on an iPhone X simulator

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works well on tableviews with adding a bottomView for buttons:

```
    let buttonsView = UIView()
    buttonsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonsView.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
    self.tableView.addSubview(buttonsView)
    
    let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
    let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
    
    buttonsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: bottomPadding ).isActive = true
    buttonsView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonsView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 88.0 + bottomPadding ).isActive = true
```